# How to control the access to BigQuery based on IP addresses?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to control the access to BigQuery datasets by IP address?

I am assuming a situation that only specific server or Global IP address can access to the BigQuery datasets with service account key.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Googler will correct me here, but I do not believe that IP filtering on dataset access is currently possible - even at the service account level.

One option could be to wrap your BigQuery dataset access by hand-rolling your own backend/API (e.g. AppEngine, Apache, etc.), and do your IP filtering logic in there before offloading the requests through to BigQuery.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your answer.
I'm worry about the situation in which a malicious third party get a service key file and try to access a certain BigQuery Dataset from different environment.
If it's happen, I think I can address the situation by disabling the key and creating the new key.

I will try to check whether "sharing dataset at the domain level" meets my request.

Answer (score -1):

The most "closed" BigQuery dataset I could create:

- Create a dataset, put tables into it.
- Change dataset permissions, remove everyone from it. Note that you can't remove all owners, so a step is missing:
- Add a service account as an owner of the dataset, then remove all other owners.

No one can query this dataset now, except the specified service account.

(when testing this wait some seconds after deleting permissions, as access might get temporarily cached)

For extra security, if you are on Google Compute Engine you can use the [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account) - which means there are is no secret key to generate or handle.