# IP filtering in BigQuery | Security around BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We are running analytics on a dataset using BigQuery, we have created views to restrict to fewer columns. We are trying to connect PowerBI to query the views.
Question is how can we restrict access to my views apart from the basic authentication support of the service account. What if the service account is compromised?

The only read I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337979/how-to-control-the-access-to-bigquery-based-on-ip-addresses/41353377#41353377).

Answer (score 1):

Since your title mentions IP filtering, it's probably worth pointing out VPC-SC, which provides additional network security controls: https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls